# How to solve this derivative of f proof?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

A function $f$ satisfies:

$$f''(x) + f'(x)g(x) - f(x) = 0$$ for some function $g$. Prove that if $f$ is $0$ at two points, then $f$ is $0$ on the interval between them.

Can someone verify my proof?

*Scratchwork:*

So let $I = [a, b]$ and $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. $g(x)$ is some function, doesn't matter. I will use the second derivative test idea:

*Proof*

Suppose $f(x) > 0 \space \forall x \in (a, b)$

$$\because f(a) = f(b) = 0 \space \exists x_1 \in (a, b) \implies f'(x_1) = 0 \tag1$$

$$f''(x_1) + \overbrace{f'(x_1)g(x_1)}^{0} - f(x_1) = 0$$

$$ \therefore f''(x_1) = f(x_1) > 0$$

I just need help to reach a contradiction please??

Comment: the exact same question was asked today. Is this some sort of homework?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $[a,b]$ it attains its maximum at some $x_1\in[a,b]$. We assume that $f(x_1)>0$. Then $x_1\in(a,b)$ and $x_1$ is a local maximum, which implies $f'(x_1)=0$ and therefore $f''(x_1)=f(x_1)>0$. But then $x_1$ is a strict (local) minimum, a contradiction. Thus, $f(x_1)\leq0$ and hence $f(x)\leq0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Now, repeat the proof with "minimum" instead of "maximum" to show that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: Why does $f(x_1) \le 0$ if $x_1$ is a local minimum? @sranthrop?

Comment: we assumed that $f(x_1)>0$ and generated a contradiction. Thus $f(x_1)\leq0$.

Comment: I do not understand, how is that a contradiction? And how did you say:

<We assume that $f(x_1)>0$. Then $x_1 \in (a,b)$ and $x_1$ is a local maximum

How is it a local maximum if $f(x_1) > 0$? Which rule are you using?

Good answer! (+1)

Comment: $x_1$ is by definition the maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, and since we assume that $f(x_1)>0$ it can't be $a$ or $b$, so it is an interior point (i.e. $x_1\in(a,b)$). Since $x_1$ is the global maximum in $[a,b]$ and an interior point, it is a local maximum.

Comment: That makes sense better, but there is still some grey area. What is the definition of the maximum of $f$ on $[a, b]$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous on a compact interval, so it attains its maximum there, i.e. $x_1\in[a,b]$ is so that $f(x_1)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$

Comment: Okay, so $f(x_1) = \sup_\{x \in [a, b]\} f(x)$ and then when you assume $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$ then $f(x_1) > 0$, there is no contradiction?

Comment: I don't assume $f(x)>0$ for (all) $x\in[a,b]$, I just assume $f(x_1)>0$. This implies (using your DGL) $f''(x_1)>0$ which is a contradiction, since $f''(x_1)>0$ means that $x_1$ is a strict local minimum.

Comment: But look at $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, it has a local minimum, which is $f(x_1)> 0$ ?

Comment: Indeed, $x_1=0$ is a local minimum, but $f(x_1)\neq\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}f(x)$.

Comment: I believe I get the proof. Because $f(x)$ is cont. on $[a, b]$ and $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, also because of the Extreme Value Theorem, $\exists  x \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(x_1)$ which follows from Rolle's theorem. Also, assume $f(x) > 0 \forall x \in (a, b)$. Then, $f(x_1) > 0$ from this hypothesis. Also:

$$f''(x_1) + f'(x_1)g(x_1) = f(x_1) > 0$$

This means,

$$f''(x_1) = f(x_1) > 0$$. This means, $f(x_1)$ is a local minimum. 

**But can you prove:**

That there cannot be a minimum for $f(x) > 0$? for some $x$??

Comment: This is not I've written. Please read again my posts. Moreover, you must nnot assume that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, as I said earlier.

Comment: @sranthop, in your answer you said: Assume $f(x_1) > 0$ where $x_1 \in (a, b)$ Okay. Then you said $f'(x_1) = 0$, okay. $f''(x_2) = f(x_1) > 0$. Then, the contradiction is that you find $f(x_1)$ is a **local minimum, not a local maximum**? Correct? But this only **contradicts for ONE $x$** what about **all** other $x \in (a, b)$?

Comment: No. In my answer I said that $x_1$ is that point at which $f$ attains its maximum. Then I assumed that $f(x_1)>0$ and found a contradiction. So $f(x_1)$, which is the maximal value of $f$, cannot be positive and must be $\leq0$. Since $f(x_1)$ is the maximum, we conclude that $f(x)\leq0$ for each point $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: This is part I dont understand:


"So $f(x_1)$, which is the maximal value of f, cannot be positive and must be $\le 0$. "

Where did you do this in your answer?

Comment: $x_1$ is a local maximum. Assume that $f(x_1)>0$. Follow my proof and you'll see that then $x_1$ is a strict local minimum, contradicting the def. of $x_1$ being a local max. Therefore, the assumption that $f(x_1)>0$ has to be rejected. Thus, $f(x_1)\leq0$.

Comment: Ah - I see now. So that comment I wrote 2 comments ago saying: "**Then, the contradiction is that you find f(x1) is a local minimum, not a local maximum**". The contradiction is $f(x_1) \le 0$, but it rather that it is not the local maximum?

Comment: Yes. The assumption $f(x_1)>0$ leads to the fact that $x_1$ must be a strict local minimum, and this contradicts the def. of $x_1$. So the assumption cannot be correct.

Comment: Then the same thing for local minimum? Assume $f(x_1) < 0$ ?

Comment: Yes. You got the idea.

Comment: But @sranthrop, there is also a minimum in $(a, b)$, which means if you let $x_1$ be the minimum ,there is no contradiction?

Comment: Think about it for a while. I'm pretty sure you can do that on your own.

Comment: Yes. If you let $x_1$ be a minimum. then: $f'(x_1) = 0$ and then assume $f(x_1) > 0$. this means: $f''(x_1) = f(x_1) > 0$. No contradiction. How do you deal with this, @sranthrop? thanks

Comment: Assume $f(x_1)<0$.

Comment: Ah - I see. Suppose, $x_1, x_2 \in (a, b)$ and we assume $f(x_1) > 0$ and $f(x_2) > 0$ let $x_2$ be the max, and let $x_1$ be the minimum. For both cases, $f'(x_1) = f'(x_2) = 0$. So: 

$$f''(x_1) = f(x_1) > 0$$ No contradiction. 

$$f''(x_2) = f(x_2) > 0$$ Contradiction. 

I see the point, it is just to get ONE contradiction. 

**Question: How can you be sure two points exist in an interval such that one is a local max and one is a local minimum?**

I must say, this is an **excellent** answer and follow up, I undeerstand much more! Thank you  !

Comment: Continuous functions attain their maximum and minimum on compact sets.

Comment: cant those be endpoints $[a, b]$? then $f'(a) =0$ is not required?

Comment: They can, but then, since $f(a)=0=f(b)$, it followed that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: I do not understand. We are trying to prove $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$? Then what did you mean about $f'(x_1) = 0$ for some $x_1$?

Answer (score 1):

The right negation is that $f(x)\ge0$ in $(a,b)$ and exist a point c | $f(c)>0$.

You have that $f''(x_1)\ge0$ (the function in that point is convex) so in that point you have a minima so there are two case

1. $f(x_1)<0$ (obviously contradiction)
2. $f(x_1)=0$ (it's impossible because this imply that $f(x)=0$  $ \forall x \in (a,b) $)

Analog for the other case

Comment: What about the case where $f(x)$ takes on both positive and negative values?

Comment: It's impossible too. 
Because if $f(x_1)$ is the first point with $f'(x_1)=0$ and it's maxima $→$ it's positive and it should be $f''(x_1)<0$ but it's impossible because$f(x_1)=f''(x_1)$. The same if $f(x_1)$ is the first point with $f'(x_1)=0$ and it's minima.

Comment: How does $f''(x_1) > 0$ imply that $f(x_1) < 0$? @DavideMarano (+1)

Comment: Because it's a minima and you start from $f(a)=0$ You could think something about increase,maxima, decrease, minima, increase, maxima decrease. But it's impossibile because all point (if we are considering $\ge0$) have $f''(x)\ge0$ and it's impossible that are maxima point.

Comment: @DavideMarano, what about first, decrease, minima, increase, maxima... so on. We are not saying ALL points $f''(x) \ge 0$ we just said $f''(x_1) > 0$? ?

Comment: that point have $f'(x)=0$

Comment: Actually, $f$ can be much more than "exponential function, sine, cosine, quadratic". It can be any twice (not necessarily continuously!) differentiable fucntion with $f(x)=f''(x)$ whenever $f'(x)=0$

Comment: ok i removed this part

Comment: @DavideMarano, you still have not explained though. How does $f''(x_1) > 0$ imply that: $f(x_1) < 0$? +1

Comment: ok i try to explain it again.

Comment: ok i try to explain it again.
Suppose that $f(x)=0$ for all point less one point such that $f(x_1)>0$. Now for Rolle Theorem we now that exist a point given that $f'(x_1)=0$. If it is $f(x_1)=0$ it's impossible because this imply that$ f(x)=0 \forall x∈(a,b)$
Now suppose it $f(x_1)>0$ but it's impossible because we have from the relation that $f''(x_1)>0$ and so it's a minima(so if you have other point for Rolle theorem are all MINIMA!!!).. so  you start from $f(a)=0$ and for have a minima you have to go down!!!.. so $f(x_1)$ must be $<0$. contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

To make what you wrote more watertight:

Starting from your assumptions, we have that $f$ is continouous, hence there are $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_1)=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$ and $f(x_2)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$. 
If $x_1\in(a,b)$, then we have a local minimum, that is $f'(x_1)=0$ and $f''(x_1)\ge 0$. Then 
$$f(x_1)=f''(x_1)+f'(x_1)g(x_1)=f''(x_1)\ge 0.$$
Of course also $f(x_1)\ge 0$ if $x_1\in\{a,b\}$, thus definitely $$\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\ge0.$$
By the same argument with $x_2$, we obtain
$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\le0.$$
Hence for arbitrary $x\in[a,b]$
$$0\le\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\le f(x)\le \sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\le 0.$$

Comment: +1, I do not however understand this. How is $\sup f(x) \le 0$ for $x_2$?

Comment: Moreover, this is only for ONE $x$, not *every $x$*

Comment: No. $\inf f\leq f(x)\leq\sup f$ for EVERY $x\in[a,b]$ by def. of $\inf$ and $\sup$.

Comment: @Lebes In the proof that shows $\inf f(x)\ge 0$, replace each occurance of  $(x_1, \inf, \ge,\text{minimum})$ with $(x_2, \sup, \le,\text{maximum})$.

Comment: When you write by the same argument with $x_2$... are you saying that $f''(x_2) < 0$ and also that $f(x_2)$ is a local maximum? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I may see a flaw. Assuming $f(x) > 0$, how can you say that **for a general x**, $f'(x_1) = 0$, this is only for the maximum and minimum $x$ points. what about the other $x$ points?