# Interesting Question about a derivative proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

I recently searched around SE, and found:

[How to solve this derivative of f proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142546/how-to-solve-this-derivative-of-f-proof)

The answer is interesting.

> "A function given that $f(x)=f''(x)+f'(x)g(x)$ could be an exponential function, sine, cosine , quadratic polynomial or $f\equiv0$. So we can say that the function is a continuous function $\in C^2$.
>
> The right negation is that $f(x)\ge0$ in $(a,b)$ and exist a point c | $f(c)>0$.
>
> You have that $f''(x_1)\ge0$ (the function in that point is convex) so in that point you have a minima so there are two case
>
> 1. $f(x_1)<0$ (obviously contradiction)
> 2. $f(x_1)=0$ (it's impossible because this imply that $f(x)=0$  $ \forall x \in (a,b) $)
>
> Analog for the other case"

But how does $f''(x_1) > 0$ show that $f(x_1) < 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: I thing the iintroductory sentence is ... redundant. Since $g$ is variable, there are many other functions possible for $f$ than those listed. - The use of $f''$ in the problem statement tells us implicitly that $f$ is to be assumed twice differentiable. - But since $g$ need not be continuous, we cannot assume that $f$ is $C^2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, but anyhow, how does it show $f(x_1) < 0$?

Comment: In the future, please ask clarification questions in the comments of the original answer. Additionally, there were better answers with complete solutions in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one half of the answer. It is missing in the original answer too because it refers to another answer.

If the function $f$ is not identically zero, then there is a positive maximum or a negative minimum $x_1$ inside the interval. By switching $f$ to $-f$ one can reduce the second to the first case. Then $f'(x_1)=0$ and thus $f''(x_1)=f(x_1)$ per equation. Now $f''(x_1)\le 0$ per concavity close to the maximum and $f(x_1)> 0 $ which is a contradiction.

Comment: (+1) good answer, but can you give me some more advice? From:

"If the function f is not identically zero, then there is a positive maximum or a negative minimum x1 inside the interval. " 

How is this true?

Comment: If there is a non-zero function value, if it is positive, then there is a positive maximum, if it is negative, then there is a negative minimum. The range of function values is an interval.

Comment: Or put another way: From the equation alone one sees that the function must have only non-positive maxima and non-negative minima inside the interval. Which severely restricts the possible ranges.

Comment: Yes, from the extreme value theorem, the maximum is, there is $x_2 \in (a, b)$ such that $f''(x_2) < 0$. And $f(x_2) > 0$ by assumption. Then, $f'(x_2) = 0$ so: $f''(x_2) > 0$ which is the contradiction? But this only tests **ONE POINT,** $x_2$, how do we prove FOR ALL $x \in (a,b)$?

Comment: How does the maximum relate to all the other points?